# Translating to R which function and cl classification to pandas library

Tags: python, pandas, k-means

I am trying to translate this:

```
n <- NROW(train)
s <-which(train$cl[-n] == state)
```

I know that which is just a comparison so I believe in pandas I could just do:

```
n = train.count()
s = train['-n'] == state
```

I am really not sure how to translate cl in R to pandas 
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need size of DataFrame use:

```
n = len(train)
```

Or:

```
n = len(train.index)
```

Or:

```
n = train.shape[0]
```

Second is OK:

```
s = train['-n'] == state
```